# feof blocks on sockets

Tags: php

on Mac OS X the following feof() call never returns.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$fh = fsockopen($hostname, 80, &$errno, &$errstr);
if ($errno) {
    print $errstr;
    exit;
}
$request = <<<request
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: $hostname
Connection: close

request;
fputs($fh,$request);
while (!feof($fh))
    echo fgets($fh);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Are you having the same problem in other platforms? Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `feof`, it's your request that isn't formatted the proper way. As you probably know, Unix-like systems uses `\n` for newline. However, a new line in HTTP is `\r\n`. You need to change your request:

```
$request = <<<request
GET / HTTP/1.1\r
Host: $hostname\r
Connection: close\r
\r\n
request;
```

Also, note that I've used `HTTP/1.1`, because the `Host` header doesn't apply to HTTP 1.0. It was introduced in 1.1. You will also see that I've put `\n` on the last line. It's because heredoc doesn't end the string with a new line automatically.

One last thing, this:

```
fsockopen($hostname, 80, &$errno, &$errstr);
```

... is wrong. It is called a *Call-time pass-by-reference*, and is deprecated. The good way is:

```
fsockopen($hostname, 80, $errno, $errstr);
```

... without the `&`. You will have the same result, but no errors will be triggered (in 5.3 at least).

Answer (score 0):

Your code generates a 'Bad Request' from Apache on my Ubuntu 10.10.

This, I think, has to do with the line endings in your request.  Replacing your heredoc request assignment with the following works:

```
$request = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n"
        . "Hostname: $hostname\r\n"
        . "Connection: close\r\n"
        . "\r\n";
```